# Properties of Petersen graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Petersen graph is graph with 10 vertices and 15 edges 
What is domination number and independence number of Petersen graph?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph

Comment: Independence Number is 4, Domination Number 3. See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PetersenGraph.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Petersen graph has domination number $3$ and independence number $4$.

Dominating set:

[image: domination number]

Independent set:

[image: Independence number]